# Type '(text: string) => void' is not assignable to type '() => any'

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I am trying to use [SearchBar](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/searchbar/) from the reactnativeelements as follows:

```
export function EditHash({ navigation, route }: ModifyHashProps) {

    const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = React.useState("");

    const handleSearchChange = (text: string) : void => setSearchQuery(text);

    return (
        <SafeAreaView>

                <SearchBar
                    placeholder="type hashtag"
                    lightTheme={true}
                    inputContainerStyle={{
                        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
                        height:30
                    }}
                    containerStyle={{
                        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        borderColor: "#E5E6E6",
                        borderRadius: 10,
                        marginLeft: 20,
                        marginRight: 20,
                    }}
                    value={searchQuery}
                    onChangeText={handleSearchChange}
                />

        </SafeAreaView>

    );
}
```

Unfortunately, the compiler complains about the `onChangeText` function assignment:

```
Type '(text: string) => void' is not assignable to type '((text: string) => void) & ((text: string) => void) & (() => any) & (() => any) & (() => any) & ((text: string) => void) & (() => any) & (() => any) & (() => any)'.
  Type '(text: string) => void' is not assignable to type '() => any'.
```

According to the type definition, it should be fine:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What if you make the argument optional?

Comment: What do you mean with optional?

Comment: Well you're passing a function where the parameter is required to something where a bunch of the definitions don't pass a parameter, so did you try changing your signature to match that?

Comment: As you can see I think it should match.

Comment: You're looking at one part of the intersection, as the error tells you (and you can also see in the screenshot) there are other parts of that intersection that are `() => any`, i.e. won't be passing the parameter.

Comment: This issue has been resolved in V4 beta